# Create Model (RAILS) for mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have to connect my Rails app to MongoDB, after some research i found a gem (mongoid).
My doubt is, how to create the model?
The collection on MongoDB looks like the example bellow:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "56fbf7e577550f39a5aea04a"
    },
    "id_test": "225|1",
    "array_ex1": [],
    "array_ex2": [
        "obj_ex1": {
            "field_obj_1": "text1",
            "field_obj_2": "text2",
            "field_obj_3": "text3",
         }
     ],
    "obj_ex2": {
       "field1: "textex1",
       "field2: "textex2",
       "field3: "textex3",
    },
    "flg_test": true
}
```

Comment: Why don't you go and check the gem's documentation?

Answer (score 7):

It's the same way..

```
rails generate model model_name
```

Also, you can specify the orm:

```
rails g active_record:model model_name
rails g mongoid:model model_name
```

And the model file will look something like this:

```
class SomeModel
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  field :id_test, type: String
  field :array_ex1, type: Array
  field :array_ex2, type: Array
  field :obj_ex2
  field :flg_test, type: Boolean
end
```

Comment: what if we are using two databases ? sqllite and Mongo

Answer (score 2):

-> Create Model

```
rails generate model modelname
```

-> If data fields will different (dynamic) for each record, you need to add following line to your model

```
 include Mongoid::Attributes::Dynamic
```

->Create Record

```
modelname.create({:field1 "valie1", :field2 "value2"})
modelname.create({:field1 "valie1"})
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to create a model in the `app/models` folder. For your example, it looks like it would be:

`app/models/singular_collection_name.rb`

```
class SingularCollectionName
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :id_test, type: String
  field :array_ex1, type: Array
  field :array_ex2, type: Array
  field :obj_ex2, type: Hash
  field :flg_test, type: Boolean

end
```

where SingularCollectionName is the collection name without pluralization.

You can read more [here](https://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/mongoid-documents/).